# Could anyone tell me something about Scheme Common-Lisp and FASL File

Tags: scheme, common-lisp

Can anyone tell me something about this file? As I know:

1. Common-Lisp and Scheme are both dialects of lisp.
2. Common-Lisp source file *.lisp can be compiled into binary file *.fasl which can be loaded faster than the source file.

Q:Can the Scheme source code *.scm be compiled into some binary file that will be loaded faster than the source code?

Thanks in advance,

joe

Comment: Please don't use Code-formatting for none-code text

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the Scheme implementation you're using has that feature.

- FASL in Racket: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/fasl.html
- FASL in Chez Scheme: http://www.scheme.com/csug8/io.html#./io:h15

Alternatively, you could compile your code to native binaries...