# How to compile scheme into native binary files?

Tags: scheme, native

I am very new to scheme. And now I am trying to compile some scheme code into binary file which will be loaded faster into interpreter. (The interpreter is a hybrid interpreter)Some one told me that I can compile the code into native binary file and then load it into interpreter. And my question is:

1. What is the native binary file?
2. How can I compile the scheme code into a native binary file?
3. How can I load native binary file into scheme interpreter?

Thanks in advance.

Joe

Suggested that I want to compile below code into native binary file:

```
(define test (lambda() (display "this is a test"))
```

And then load the bianry file into interpreter and call the function "test".

Comment: A useful piece of information would be: Which Scheme environment are you using? They're all different.

Comment: Yes Use Chicken scheme, Bigloo, Gambit or Racket all can produce native machine code. The first 3 through intermediate C translation step which requires a gcc installed.

Answer (score 0):

See this question about [FASLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574568/could-anyone-tell-me-something-about-scheme-common-lisp-and-fasl-file) from a couple days ago.

Some Schemes can output a FASt-Loading binary representation of data rather than a plain-text representation, but it depends on whether your Scheme even has this feature.

Answer (score -1):

> What is the native binary file?

That depends on your particular Scheme implementation.

> How can I compile the scheme code into a native binary file?

That depends on your particular Scheme implementation.

> How can I load native binary file into scheme interpreter?

That depends on your particular Scheme implementation.